# I'm trying to run a powershell command to uninstall a WinPcap, but after trying trying different methods I'm still not succesfull?

Tags: powershell, cmd

Below is the script that I'm running that always gives either a Program error or a `The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet error`. The service stops but the `Invoke-Command` seems to be the problem.

```
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\DTServerScript\Servers.txt"

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
  $Status = ""
  do 
  {
  #Stopping Service
    $ServiceAgent = Get-Service -ComputerName $Server | Where {$_.Name -like "*oneagent*"}
    Write-Host "Pending Stop on $Server"
    Stop-Service $ServiceAgent
    sleep 1
    $Status = $ServiceAgent.Status    
  } until ($Status -eq "Stopped")

  Write-Host "Service state is $Status on $Server"

  # Execute config change

  # Invoking Commands on Server
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server {cmd.exe/ c:\Program Files (x86)\WinPcap\uninstall.exe /S }

  write-host "Service is starting on $Server"

  # Starting Service

  Start-Service $ServiceAgent
  $ServiceAgent = Get-Service -ComputerName $Server | Where {$_.Name -like "*oneagent*"}
  $Status = $ServiceAgent.Status
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the path and using braces around the name containing ()..

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server { & $Env:ComSpec /C "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\WinPcap\uninstall.exe" /S }
```